# Easiest way to do idle processing in a Scala Actor?

Tags: scala, actor

I have a scala actor that does some work whenever a client requests it. When, and only when no client is active, I would like the Actor to do some background processing.

What is the easiest way to do this? I can think of two approaches:

1. Spawn a new thread that times out and wakes up the actor periodically. A straight forward approach, but I would like to avoid creating another thread (to avoid the extra code, complexity and overhead).
2. The Actor class has a reactWithin method, which could be used to time out from the actor itself. But the documentation says the method doesn't return. So, I am not sure how to use it.

**Edit; a clarification:**

Assume that the background task can be broken down into smaller units that can be independently processed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I see I need to put my 2 cents. From the author's answer I guess the "priority receive" technique is exactly what is needed here. It is possible to find discussion in "[Erlang: priority receive question here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960016/erlang-priority-receive)". The idea is to accept high priority messages first and to accept other messages only in absence of high-priority ones.

As Scala actors are very similar to Erlang, a trivial code to implement this would look like this:

```
def act = loop {
  reactWithin(0) {
    case msg: HighPriorityMessage => // process msg
    case TIMEOUT =>
      react {
        case msg: HighPriorityMessage => // process msg
        case msg: LowPriorityMessage => // process msg
      }
  }
}
```

This works as follows. An actor has a mailbox (queue) with messages. The `receive` (or `receiveWithin`) argument is a partial function and Actor library looks for a message in a mailbox which can be applied to this partial function. In our case it would be an object of `HighPriorityMessage` only. So, if Actor library finds such a message, it applies our partial function and we are processing a message of high priority. Otherwise, `reactWithin` with timeout 0 calls our partial function with argument `TIMEOUT` and we immediately try to process any possible message from the queue (as it waits for a message we cannot exclude a possiblity to get `HighPriorityMessage`).

Comment: Although my solution works in practice, I think this is more idiomatic, hence accepting it. I originally wanted to use reactWithin but didn't find any documentation on `TIMEOUT`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem you describe is **not well suited to the actor sub-system**. An `Actor` is designed to sequentially process its message queue:

- What should happen if the actor is performing the *background* work and a new task arrives?

*An actor can only find out about this is it is continuously checking its `mailbox` as it performs the background task. How would you implement this (i.e. how would you code the background tasks as a unit of work so that the actor could keep interrupting and checking the mailbox)?*

- What should happen if the actor has many background tasks in its mailbox in front of the main task?

*Do these background tasks get thrown away, or sent to another actor? If the latter, how can you prevent CPU time being given to that actor to perform the tasks?*

All in all, it sounds much more like you need to explore some grid-style software that can run in the background (like Data Synapse)!

Comment: I understand your concern. But it is critical that the background task I want to run _has_ to be done when the actor is not doing anything. To ans your questions: 1. The background task can be broken into smaller units. It's ok if the actor finishes doing the unit of background work it is currently doing before processing a normal request.  2. Hoping to use Actor.mailboxSize to ignore background tasks when others are waiting in queue.

Answer (score 2):

Just after asking this question I tried out some completely whacky code and it seems to work fine. I am not sure though if there is a gotcha in it.

```
import scala.actors._

object Idling

object Processor extends Actor {
  start

  import Actor._

  def act() = {
    loop {

      // here lie dragons >>>>>
      if (mailboxSize == 0) this ! Idling
      // <<<<<<

      react {
        case msg:NormalMsg => {
          // do the normal work
          reply(answer)
        }

        case Idling=> {
          // do the idle work in chunks
        }

        case msg => println("Rcvd unknown message:" + msg)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

Any code inside the argument of `loop` but before the call to `react` seems to get called when the Actor is about to wait for a message. I am sending a `Idling` message to self here. In the handler for this message I ensure that the mailbox-size is 0, before doing the processing.

Comment: The only way that this can work is if you are sending the idle tasks to this actor *not* through messages. Otherwise, any idle task will result in a mailbox with one item in it

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Not sure I understand. This code works in practice, and I am sending the idle task via a message.

Comment: From your own answer I can suggest that you are inventing a "priority receive" (originating from Erlang, but can be implemented using Scala actors)

Comment: @HRJ - how can the actor have any idle tasks in its message queue if its `mailbox` is empty? It surely must be the case that the actor is getting the idle tasks from somewhere else...